# Algoritmo linguagem C - Multiplicação

Tags: c, loop

> Traduza para a linguagem C: tome um número pelo teclado e repita a operação de multiplicar ele por três (imprimindo o novo valor) até que ele seja maior do que 100. Ex.: se o usuário digita 5, deveremos observar na tela a seguinte sequência: 5 15 45 135.

Eu não quero resposta eu quero uma explicação lógica sobre o exercício para eu poder resolver sozinho ele. Eu fiz isso daqui inicialmente:

```
int main()
{
    int num, i, aux = 1;

    printf("digite um numero\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    for(i=3; i<=3; i++)
    {
        if(aux<=100)
        {
            aux=num*i;
            printf("%i\n", aux);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Eu não quero resposta eu quero uma explicação lógica sobre o exercício para eu poder resolver` Te dei um voto positivo na questão, adoraria poder dar outro só pela sua atitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quer a lógica:

```
Enquanto   numero < 100 :
     numero = numero * 3;
     Imprime( numero) ;
```

Sugiro que verifique se a entrada é menor que 0, pois deverá ter um tratamento diferenciado para isso. Ou que troque *todas as variáveis* que interajam com `num` para `unsigned int` pois ao misturar ambas poderá ter problemas no casting e acabar tendo valores inesperados.

EDITADO:

O que escrevi não é bem portugol e sim um pseudo código. O melhor programa que ainda funciona de portugol é o [visualg](http://www.guanabara.info/2007/09/visualg-v25/) que possui [essa documentação](http://www.cafw.ufsm.br/~bruno/disciplinas/introd_programacao/materiais/visualg/help/refer.htm)

Seguindo a sintaxe do visualg:

```
enquanto numero <= 100 faca
   numero <- numero * 3
   escreva (numero:3)
fimenquanto
```

Comment: nossa obrigado na verdade eu preciso voltar aler portugol ou fazer alguns programas em narrativo no papel antes se vc tiver algum link legal pra min ver isso vlw

Comment: nossa cara eu fui testar agora o programa ey fui meio burro neh eueuheuhe era so guardar o valor da variavel na propia variavel se nao ela vai so se repetir e descartar o valor anterior lol

Comment: Não recomendo usar unsigned para representar valores não-negativos em C. É muito fácil acabar tropeçando em uma conversão de signed pra unsigned e fazer um número negativo virar um número grandão. Eu preferiria deixar tudo signed e fazer um `if(n <= 0)` pra ver se a entrada do usuário é não-positiva.

Comment: @hugomg editado, valeu pela sugestão.

Comment: É bem mais fácil trocar todos os unsigneds pra signed do que cuidadosamente trocar os signeds pra unsigned. Pra falar a verdade, a única hora em que unsigned é essencial é quando vc está mexendo com bitmasks ou implementando alguma função de hash que faz uso do overflow bem definido dos unsigneds.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi no enunciado o programa não vai imprimir 135 pois 135 é maior que 100.
Você precisa mudar esse for. No for que você criou ele só vai dar um laço, pois no fim do primeiro faço i já vai ser maior que 3. E se você mudar o i<=3 ele vai multiplicar num por 3 4 5 etc.

O programa deve dar laços enquanto aux for menor ou igual a 100, neste caso eu usaria while.
destro do enquanto você vai imprimir o valor aux e abaixo de aux multiplica-lo por 3 e fecha o while, ai então o programa vai imprimir aux multiplicado por 3, e fazer a mesma coisa novamente até aux ser maior que 100.

Editado:

```
for(i=0;i<=num;i++) 
{ 
if(num<=100) 
    { 
    num=num*3; 
    printf("%i\n", num); 
}
```

E neste caso o for ainda vai estar errado, pois assim ele vai rodar pra sempre, quer dizer, em quanto i aumenta um por loop(laço) num vai ser multiplicado por 3. Então num  sempre vai sempre vai ser maior que i. Além for é uma estrutura "para" e neste caso não é necessário, use while que é uma estrutura enquanto.

```
 while(num<=100){
     printf("%i\n", num);         
     num=num*3; 
 }
```

Alem disso como eu disse antes o printf tem que esta na frente do num=num*3 para poder imprimir o numero digitado pelo usuário.

Comment: massa vlw na verdade sim o for tah bem errado eu tava vendo o i numca vai ser maior ou q o propio numero entao i pode ser i<=num
acredito eu se eu conceguir arrumar esse programa eu posto aqui vlw

Comment: for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
{
  if(num<=100)
  {
     num=num*3;
     printf("%i\n", num);
  }
}

Comment: aqui eu certo aparece tudo como pede no exemplo do exercicio esta do geito q digitei ali so nao sei por que ficou em 1 linha so

Answer (score 1):

Amigo se você pensar de forma programável ficará bem mais fácil de executar sua tarefa, vou te dar um exemplo de como pensar sua execução:

`receba` o numero do teclado,
`enquanto` número for `menor ou igual` a `100`(o programa pede que ele seja maior que isso),
`multiplique` por `3`,
`se` `maior` que `100`,`imprima e encerre`(pause).

Pensando desta forma, veja que ficará extremamente fácil fazer isso em linguagem C ou qualquer outra linguagem, depois disso com tudo pronto, se houver erros, basta procurar os motivos dos mesmos.

Bom treino.